# Will css text-shadow property takes inches(in) as parameter?

Tags: html, css

You are developing an HTML5 page that includes several paragraph elements.
You have the following requirements:
Add a drop shadow that is one inch below the textin the paragraph
Set the radius of the drop shadow to five pixels
You need to style the paragraphs to meet the requirements.
Which CSS style should you use?

```
A.text-shadow: 72pt 0pt 5pt

B.text-shadow: 5px lin 0px;

C.text-shadow: 72pt 5em 0px

D.text-shadow:72pt 0em 5px;
```

Option **B** seems to be right but I don't see any shadow. I see shadow output only for option **A & D**. Which is right?  I'm confused :(

Please refer `http://jsfiddle.net/4v4yu/`

Comment: What output you get, that is the proper way :)

Comment: The character in B before "in" is a lowercase L

Comment: Michael Butscher - its 1 not small letter 'L'

Comment: @Raghavendra It's not, it's currently a lower case L. It may be supposed to be a 1, and if you change it to a 1, a text shadow is drawn.

Comment: MLeFevre  - Refer `http://jsfiddle.net/4v4yu/12/` Still doesn't wrk!

Comment: I got this exact ptoblem in some exams and the only thing i can say is: all of the four Answers are wrong. If the text shadow should be one inch below the paragraph, and the radius of the shadow has to be set to 5 pixels the correct answer would be: text-shadow: 0px 1in 5px; the first and second parameter is for horizontal and vertical alignment (we only wanted to show the text below the paragraph,there was no talk about horizontal alignment) the third parameter setx the blur. Since B doesn't set any blur at all, B completely misses the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your option B & C you didn't set a value to display the shadow (0px)

```
A.text-shadow: 72pt 0pt 5pt

B.text-shadow: 5px lin **0px**

C.text-shadow: 72pt 5em **0px**

D.text-shadow:72pt 0em 5px
```

Here your jsfiddle fix : http://jsfiddle.net/4v4yu/10/

You should take a look at the w3c documentation for all the allowed units : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#length-value

Answer (score 0):

I'm no master on CSS, however if i were to do text-shadow i'd use the following:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
```

Or with rgba

```
text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
```

I've not seen option B used before, i could be wrong, but i know this method works fine.

Syntax:

```
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur color;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: B is correct.text-shadow: 5px 1in 0px;
box-shadow:5px 1in 0px #343434;
the first value: Shading is horizontally, in the upper value the shadow goes to the right but if you give it a negative value, the shadow goes to the left.
The second value: The shadow marker is vertical, in the second value it creates the shadow at the bottom of the element. If we give it a negative value, the shadow is created at the top of the image.
The third value: Indicates Blur. The higher the value of the Blur, the shadows will be displayed and if the value is lowered, the shadows will appear dense.
The fourth value: Specifies the shade color you can select for each color and use the hexadecimal and RGBA color methods to color the shade.

Comment: Explanation: We set the second argument (vertical) to one inch (1in).
Note
Syntax
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur color;
Note: The text-shadow property attaches one or more shadows to text. The property is a
comma-separated list of shadows, each specified by 2 or 3 length values and an optional
color. Omitted lengths are 0.
* h-shadow
Required. The position of the horizontal shadow. Negative values are allowed
* v-shadow
Required. The position of the vertical shadow. Negative values are allowed
* blur
Optional. The blur distance
* color
Optional. The color of the shadow.

Comment: Hi abas! can you please edit your answer to contain also your comment? it'll make easier to everyone to read it. Please consider also formatting :)