# Text shadow one inch below the text

Tags: css, html

I have the following question for exam 70-480, but in my opinion all possible answers are incorrect.

Question is:
Add a drop shadow that is one inch below the text in the paragraph.
Set the radius of the drop shadow to 5px.

Possible answers are:

- **A**  `text-shadow: 72pt 0pt  5pt`
- **B**  `text-shadow: 5px in 0px`
- **C**  `text-shadow: 72pt  5em  0px`
- **D**  `text-shadow: 72pt 0em 5px`

Can anyone tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263836/will-css-text-shadow-property-takes-inchesin-as-parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/4v4yu/13/

Answer choice A reads:

```
h1 {text-shadow: 5pt .1in 2pt}
```

and it seems to be an ***incorrect*** answer, because:

**[1]** It shows *point* one inch below, not one inch below.

**[2]** It reads in `pt`, not `px`.

None of the other answer choices are correct, either, because none of them can show exactly one inch below, because it depends on the PPI (Pixels Per Inch) of the screen to tell how many pixels are one inch.

From this data, you can conclude there **is no correct answer** to that question.

Comment: The following would be correct to answer the question: `h1 {text-shadow: 0px 1in 5px}`.  The first option can be whatever, it will always be one inch below.  The blur radius (third option) is set to `5px`.  The second option (y distance/vertical distance) is set to 1 inch, so basically the PPI (Pixels Per Inch) of your screen.

Comment: I dont know what the meant with radio of the drop shadow, is that blur? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

Comment: @LuisValencia I'm referring to your question, I thought you meant `blur`, as in `blur ratio`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer should be:

```
text-shadow: 0px 1in 5px;
```

Refer http://jsfiddle.net/venudil/kyzykfwf/

Comment: Reason: first part is for h-shadow 0px, second part is for v-shadow 1in and last part is for blur-radius 5px. Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/venudil/kyzykfwf/ .

Answer (score 2):

None of them.

You're correct, none of them gives shadow 1 inch (equals 72pt or 6em approx. ) below with 5 px blur.

So the correct answer should be

```
text-shadow: 0 1in 5px;
```

or

```
text-shadow: 0pt 72pt 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

**D** is the most correct.

[Reference: CSS Text Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-shadow)

Note:
All options are incorrect nearest correct answers are **B** or **D**.

```
#obj {text-shadow: <x-offset> <y-offset> <blur-radius> <color>; }
<x-offset> +n right -n left
<y-offset> +n bottom -n top
```

1 inch below means `<y-offset>` is 1in or 72 pt

Hence actually answer must be

```
0px, 1in, 5px
or
0px, 72pt, 5px
```